# Javascript use anonymous function inside class methods

Tags: javascript

I am refactoring working code in to `class`. I am getting an error where I am loading some `Json` and parsing it. This code works fine as a `function` but not inside a `class` `method`.

Code:

```
class MemoryCards {
    
    constructor() {
        this.gameData = [];
        this.cardData = [];

        this.currentLives = 0;
        this.levelLives = 0;
        this.level = 1;

        this.hasFlippedCard = false;
        this.lockDeck = false;
        this.firstCard, this.secondCard;
        this.trackMatches = 0;

        this.cardSelection = [];
    }

    startGame () {
        this.loadJSON(function(response) {
            this.gameData = JSON.parse(response);}, 
            'gameData.json');
    }

    loadJSON(callback, file) {   

        var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        xobj.open('GET', `assets/data/${file}`, false);
        xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                callback(xobj.responseText);
            }
        };
        xobj.send(null);  
    }
}
```

Error:

```
game.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'gameData' of undefined
    at game.js:21
    at XMLHttpRequest.xobj.onreadystatechange (game.js:68)
    at MemoryCards.loadJSON (game.js:71)
    at MemoryCards.startGame (game.js:20)
    at (index):77
```

Comment: Use an arrow function, `this.loadJSON(response => { this.gameData = ... })`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement **Arrow Function**:

```
startGame () {
  this.loadJSON((response) => {
  this.gameData = JSON.parse(response);
 }, 'gameData.json');
}
```

Why it Works?

It is because of the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword. The **this** keyword is referring to the **Global Object** by default. **functions** have their own block scope but **arrow** and **normal** functions have different world when it comes to looking for **global object**.

This code or **normal function** is looking for it's **parent object** and that is the **startGame** function.

```
function(response) {
 this.gameData = JSON.parse(response);
}, 'gameData.json')
```

but this **arrow function** is looking for the **last parent object** and that is **MemoryCards**

```
(response) => {
  this.gameData = JSON.parse(response);
 }, 'gameData.json')
```

Think of this way the **arrow function** is looking for the **LAST** scope or **{ }**

Comment: You should include an explanation as to why the arrow function solves this issue

Comment: Ok, I will just a min.